# Use Facebook Graph API to Remove Friend Connections

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question about weather something is or is not possible with Facebook's API.

Can a server side script have access to a users account and remove a tag associated with another person? Or remove photos that has a particular friend in it (obviously only if the person has been tagged)?

For instance maybe I want to remove all connections I have with another person, can the Facebook API graph allow me to do so if I specify the individual?

I am not looking for how to do so, I am first trying to find out if this is even possible. I have been pouring over documentation but it is something that I do not completely understand and I will not be the one writing code.

Any help or direction will be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't unfriend a person through the API.  Even deleting photos is impossible, unless the app created the photos in the first place.  There are numerous other threads on SO about this, as well as forums posts about people that have struggled with problems in the recent past.  You can't even delete a tag of a photo through the API even though DELETE methods exist in the documentation and indicate that it should work.  When making the calls people receive oauth error results, and there is probably still a pending bug report about this behavior, but no expectation that FB plans to fix it anytime soon.

In general they are happy to let you add a lot of content, but they don't want to let you remove it -- and that goes double for the API.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. Do you happen to have links to some of the materials you have mentioned? I have tried searching SO but apparently I am doing something wrong, maybe just not using the right keywords. Thanks again!

Comment: If it's not in the documentation it typically doesn't exist in the API, there's very few exceptions to that rule